# Cambiar la autorizacion en el header

Tags: reactjs

estoy probando con apollo-client y react-apollo-hooks, consigo que el servidor me duelva el token cuando uso la mutacion, pero no se como seguir y cambiar el header para que use el token recien recibido.

El cliente apollo esta iniciado de la siguiente manera:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
  request: async operation => {
    operation.setContext({
      headers: {
        authorization: null
      }
    });
  }
});
```

El componente para usar la mutacion es el siguiente:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css'
import { useMutation } from 'react-apollo-hooks';
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

const LOGIN = gql`
  mutation login($email: String!,$password: String!) {
    login(email: $email, password: $password) {
      token
    }
  }
`;


function App() {
  const [ email, setEmail ] = useState('');
  const [ password, setPassword ] = useState('');

  const login = useMutation(LOGIN, {
    variables: {
      email: email,
      password: password
    }
  });


  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    login().then(token => {
      // console.log(token)
    }).catch(err => {
      // console.log(err)
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="email"
          placeholder="Enter your email"
          onChange={e => setEmail(e.currentTarget.value)}
        />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Password" onChange={e => setPassword(e.currentTarget.value)} />
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

El contexto inicial del cliente llega correctamente a los resolvers del servidor, supongo que tendra que haber alguna manera de poder accerder a la propiedad request del cliente para poder actualizar los headers. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

generalmente cuando se recibe el token desde el servidor, éste se lo deja en el localStore, mas o menos asi:

```
operation.setContext({
  headers: {
    authorization: null,
    "token": token
  }
});
```

y en el form de login...

```
localStorage.setItem('token', token);
```